# Updating 'hidden' binary data in ASP.NET MVC on HTML5 'drop' event

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html

I need to figure out how to base64 encode the response from an HTML5 FileReader ...

Here's the problem - I've added a 'drop' event listener on a div so you can drag-n-drop an image file on to my page ... this is an ASP.NET MVC3 Razor form which has an @html.HiddenFor(...) field which contains a byte array which represents an image ...

If the user drops a file on to my div, then I want to update the 'value' of my hidden input field.

My client-side drop handler looks a bit like this:

```
dropArea.addEventListener("drop", function (evt) {

    var draggedFiles = evt.dataTransfer.files;

    if (typeof (draggedFiles) != "undefined") {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                    return function (e) {
                        var hiddenInput = document.getElementById("myMvcHiddenInputField");
                        hiddenInput.value = base64.encode(e.target.result);
                    };
                })(draggedFiles[0]);

                reader.readAsBinaryString(draggedFiles[0]);
            }
        }

        xhr.open("post", "/MyController/SetTempImage", true);

        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", draggedFiles[0].fileName);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", draggedFiles[0].fileSize);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", draggedFiles[0].type);

        xhr.send(draggedFiles[0]);

        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
    }
}, false);
```

... the problem lies in how I'm handling the response from the FileReader ... I need to re-encode the results in a way that ASP.NET is expecting the hidden field (base64.encode is a jquery library I downloaded ... I'm pretty sure it's not what I need here, as I don't think it is designed to cope with encoding binary data)

I guess my question is, when updating 'hidden' byte arrays in MVC pages, how do I encode file data on the client so that it can re-integrate with my model data when it's posted back to the server?

... It's late ... I suspect that sounds like gibberish ... but if anyone can make sense of my problem, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but try:

```
reader.readAsDataURL(draggedFiles[0]);
```